# How to inject the FragmentManger into interface in Android Fragment with Dagger Hilt?

Tags: android, android-fragments, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt, fragmentmanager

I will show my sample code:

```
interface ErrorDialogInterface {
    fun show(title: String)
}

class ErrorDialogImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val fragmentManager: FragmentManager
) : ErrorDialogInterface {
    override fun show(title: String) {
        MyDialog.create().show(fragmentManager, TAG)
    }
}
class BaseFragmentWithError: Fragment() {
    @Inject lateinit var errorDialogInterface: ErrorDialogInterface
}
```

I want to inject the `errorDialogInterface` into the Fragment. However, its implementation contains the dynamic param (which is `FragmentManager` from `Fragment`).

Is it possible to do that with Dagger Hilt?

Thanks for supporting guys.